# How to launch a mac application without a terminal window

Tags: c++, user-interface, macos, terminal

I've written an open-source c++ application and it works fine on Windows and Linux, I finally got a Mac Mini (with 10.5.8) so I've just been testing the Mac version.

My application works fine when running it from inside a terminal window and typing **./appname** , but if instead I double click on it from the finder, then it opens a termnial window first and then runs my app but it doesn't seem to set the working directory to the correct location so my app dies.

How do I make my app so when it launches by being double clicked on it doesn't open a terminal window first and how can I have the current directory set to the apps location automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac binaries are set to be opened with the 'Terminal' program; there's no way around that, except by making a full application package, or have another program launch it via `system` or something like that.

When double-clicking on a binary, the terminal window opens with `~` as the current directory. I suggest you use `chdir(2)` in your program to ensure it is running in the right directory if you need it in the first place.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, now my app runs but the terminal window stays on top of my app's window. Do you know how to hide or close the terminal window?

Comment: @KPexEA: you can't have it both ways unfortunately - you either write a generic command-line tool or you write a proper Mac app with a GUI, with a bundle, .plist etc.

Comment: @Paul R, I do want it to be a proper Mac app. Do you know of somewhere that documents how to make it into a proper app. I'm using a makefile to build it so if I can add "make bundle" to my makefile that packages it all up that would be best. It's a single exe, no seperate data files are needed.

Comment: @KPexEA: you can start with the info here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html