# OSX - How to show no terminal window when I launch my executable?

Tags: macos

I'm developing a C application for OSX with gcc.
When I launch my application with double click in finder a terminal window is shown. My application only does some basic operations and exits. Is there a way to prevent the terminal window from showing up?

In win32 I can set the subsystem to WINDOWS in PE executable. Is there something analogous for OSX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how current this is, but... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2504876/2836621